# pcl_ros nodelets do not exist

Tags: pcl, nodelet, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with some of the built-in [pcl_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros) nodelets. I have a VoxelGrid filter and passthrough filter working fine, but when I try to run the SACSegmentation nodelet as decribed in [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/SACSegmentationFromNormals%20planar%20segmentation), I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1427820107.811356547]: Failed to load nodelet [/normal_estimation] of type [pcl/NormalEstimation]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class pcl/NormalEstimation with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzi depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register freenect_camera/driver image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_rotate/image_rotate image_view/disparity image_view/image nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus openni2_camera/OpenNI2DriverNodelet openni_camera/driver pcl/BAGReader pcl/BoundaryEstimation pcl/CropBox pcl/ExtractIndices pcl/FPFHEstimation pcl/FPFHEstimationOMP pcl/MomentInvariantsEstimation pcl/NodeletDEMUX pcl/NodeletMUX pcl/NormalEstimationOMP pcl/PCDReader pcl/PCDWriter pcl/PassThrough pcl/PointCloudConcatenateDataSynchronizer pcl/PointCloudConcatenateFieldsSynchronizer pcl/ProjectInliers pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval pcl/VoxelGrid pointcloud_to_laserscan/pointcloud_to_laserscan_nodelet stereo_image_proc/disparity stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2
[ERROR] [1427820107.860576381]: Failed to load nodelet [/planar_segmentation] of type [pcl/SACSegmentationFromNormals]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class pcl/SACSegmentationFromNormals with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  ...
```

So some of the nodelets apparently aren't being recognized as nodelets by ROS on my system. They aren't listed in the [pcl_nodelets.xml](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/indigo-devel/pcl_ros/pcl_nodelets.xml) file, which is where I'd expect to see them. But I haven't had all that much experience with nodelets to know whether that's true or if I'm just doing something wrong. So is there anything I need to do to make these nodelets recognized?

Or perhaps they've been removed for some reason with the tutorials still existing? That particular filter isn't documented on the main page, anyway.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206352/pcl_ros-nodelets-do-not-exist/) by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3562 on 2015-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like there was a divergence between the nodelets defined on hydro-devel and indigo-devel due to a pull request I didn't cherry pick to indigo. Keep an eye on this ticket for fixes https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/86.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Galadriel1233](https://answers.ros.org/users/37085/galadriel1233/) on 2018-11-13**:
I know this was posted a long time ago, but I faced the same issue and just included the relevant hpp file from the impl folder and it solved the issue. Just wanna help someone who faced the issue